# How can i link only Bad plugins to my C program in Gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

Actually,

While executing a c program which is of Gstreamer,

We are using

```
 `pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0` a.c `pkg-config --libs -gstreamer-1.0`.
```

Above command will link the whole gstreamer package to C program.

But, I would like to link only gst-plugins-bad to my C program.

Can it possible??

If so How?

Answer (score 0):

This command will link the base GStreamer library to your application. This does NOT include plugins at all. In fact when you execute your GStreamer application it will search a couple of paths to look for GStreamer plugins and load them dynamically.

You can statically link plugins if you like but you will need to do GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE() and GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER() for each plugin you desire and link the static plugin version to your application.